# Constants for each instance of a matlab class

Tags: matlab, object, properties, constants, instance

I want to save data to a constant field (different for each instance).
Think of that like a fiel with the creation date of the object.
I can not find out, how to do that. Reading [Property Attributes](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html) and [Properties with constant values](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html) tells me that constants can only be for the whole class (a kind of static).
Is there a solution without using a variable property (not meaning dynamic property)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for an [immutable property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/mutable-and-immutable-properties.html), rather than a constant.

In Java, this is basically a final attribute, whereas a constant is a like final static attribute.